# Eclipse Translator App - Translating words separately - not with characters behind or in front of it

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

I'm making an app that translates text to another language. Input of the user goes into an EditText Box.
It's an offline app and I prefer not to use any databases. This my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_activity); 

    Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChkCmd);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    chkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = input.getText().toString();
            if(str!=null){
                str = str.replace("Hello", "Hallo");
                str = str.replace("World", "Wereld");

                display.setText(str);
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
```

It works fine. Only thing is, when someone puts in the word "Worldview" or "Worldwide" this way it would be translated to: "Wereldview" or "Wereldwide". It translates the word + the characters before (or after) it.

How do I make the code so it will only translate the word "World" and if it is misspelled by the user (ex "yWorld") it returns "yWorld" instead of yWereld?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use replaceAll method & word boundary regex `\\b` if you just want to match the word `World` and not `Worldwide`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\bWorld\\b", "Wereld");
```

Instead of:

```
str = str.replace("World", "Wereld");
```

---

**BTW:** should't be `Wereld` replaced by `World` ? Then it should be:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\bWereld\\b", "World");
```